# Lotus Notes Eclipse Java UI API - multiple lines

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes, lotus

I'm working on a sidebar plugin that needs to update the body field of a calendar entry when it's opened. I got the update to work using the `NotesUIDocument` API, but I can't seem to write a multi-lined (carriage return/line feed/newline) message in the body.

I've tried all the usual culprits.. \n, \r\n, char(10), char(13), .appendText....  I was able to update the backend doc, and close/reopen but that's cheesey.

I know the issue is with the .setText function..but what other way is there?

For example, the following line works fine..

```
NotesUIDocument.getField("Body").setText("hi");
```

But I can't find a way to add a new line for the next bit of text.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Have you tried reading an exiisting multii-line body field to see what you get, and writing it back to see if it's preserved?  Apart from that, or going the back-end route, maybe your best best is probably to use Session.evaluate("@Newline",doc) to return a vector containing a string containing the newline char, and append that. No idea if it will work. The NotesUIDocument and NotesUIField classes are relatively for the Notes Java API, the doc for both of them states "not intended to be implemented by clients", and it's not clear how (or if) they handle rich text fields.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.. unfortunately the only way to append the vector is toString it, and that just adds that square box to the field.   I can use the insertHTML, but I can't figure out how to get to the 'body' field in the UI.